# Differences between user and sessions in API and Analytics UI

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I´m facing an issue with user and sessions data:  i'm getting both user and sessions from API, and for the session it matches, but not for users. I'm using HIGH PRECISION sampling data in both cases, and the segment its Paid Traffic (gaid::-4)
Any idea about what can be happening?
Thanks and regards,
Emiliano

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but HIGH PRECISION doesn't guarantee unsampled data (especially with a segment).
Since sampling can be avoided for small data points, 
if users from API and from GA UI for short date range (like one day) match or almost match, then we should say they match.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post would be better as a comment. Please earn enough rep so that you may comment on questions.

Comment: Please use comments instead of answers to provide advises.

Comment: Fabio and Richard, I think Suhkjin actually adequately answered the question. The answer elucidated the misconception the questioner had with respect to `HIGH PRECISION` and advised that they should shorten the date range and gave a valid interpretation of when sampling should accepted as the final answer. As a community I think we should be welcoming when new comers willing share their knowledge.

Comment: So, it could be considered valid small differences? I dont think that is right, it is very difficult to justify. Maybe an example can give me a better scenario.